# Bitcoin not received!

Tags: transactions, bitpay, copay

Bitcoin not received in copay or bit pay wallet but shows up on Blockchain.

Blockchain website: https://blockchain.info/address/1MeHHf8AqqCFwgQCYZ7BcqM8gLZ462cpdW

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: What else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

My bitcoin is received but there was just a one day delay.